# java application not connect with a specific database in mysql on localhost,connection refused error comes

Tags: java, exception, connection, mysql-error-1064

My java application is not connect with a specific database in MySQL on local host.'Connection refused' named error coming when I am trying to connect.

I have checked also service of MySQL its working because there is two db on local host, I am able to connect with one Db. I have googled all the things but my problem still not resolved.

Comment: i have checked also service of MySQL its working  because there is two db on local host , i am able to connect with one D.i have googled all the things but my problem still not resolved.

Comment: Error 1064 stands for sql syntax error, check the query

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Bind address

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) to see if you have altered the my.cnf|ini configuration file on mysql correctly.

Also if you are trying to connect using different machine then you have to create a user and grant him privileges like this to make the database available remotely

CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';

GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'%';

Wildcard % is used to give access to any IP connecting your machine.